# UITabBarContoller change not selected item text color

Tags: xcode, uitabbarcontroller

[image]

How to change here not selected item to white like selected item?

Here is my attributes:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the tab bar item's text color programmatically by using a subclass of UITabBarController and in `viewDidLoad()` of the subclass, add the following code for the selected and normal state colors. You can also modify the font if needed as per your requirements.

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.font: selectedFont], for: .selected)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.font: normalFont], for: .normal)
```